# CMAKE finds package but does not link libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, mingw, mingw32

I'm trying to compile a project with CMAKE and make with MinGW32-make.exe.  My CMakeLists.txt looks like so:

```
#####################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0) 
project (TestProject)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable (main.exe main.cpp)
#####################################
```

Running "CMAKE -G "MinGW Makefiles" runs fine, but when I try to make with "MinGW32-make.exe" I get the following error:

```
25:39: fatal error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

When I look in the Makefile, I can't find the text "OpenCV" anywhere.  In which file is the OPENCV directory supposed to be identified?

Comment: It is `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable which contains directory with OpenCV headers. You should use it instead of `OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR` for `include_directories()` call. You may output content of variable using `message()` command. Note, that directory path needn't to contain *OpenCV* substring.

Comment: I followed your advice and used the line: "message(STATUS "OPENCV DIRECTORY: " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}) and it returned an empty value, same for _DIR.  When it finds the package shouldn't it set this variable?

Comment: I took a second look, capitalization is what tripped me up.  It now successfully links the OpenCV directory, thank you!  Now every function i'm using from OpenCV gives an 'undefined reference' error.  I suppose I have to use "target_link_libraries" for each individual dynamic library I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not arrive to link libraries, the system doesn't find the opencv headers this is because your include directories are no correctly set.

It is very important to specify where is your OpenCV build directory which is located your OpencvConfig.cmake file.

Besides you need to link your libraries with target_link_libraries.

So in conclusion your cmake code should be something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0) 
project( TestProject )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable( main main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( main ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: Yep, you nailed it.  I had gotten that far but was missing the "OpenCV_LIBS" variable in my target_link_libraries.  Thanks!

Comment: But a further question, how does cmake know where to initially look for the  "OpencvConfig.cmake" file?  Does it just look in the PATH variable?

Comment: If you put Opencv build directory in your path as environment variable, cmake will automatically find it. But, in other case you have to specify the variable OPENCV_DIR which is your opencv build directory.

Comment: Well that's weird because I have both OPENCV_DIR and the path variable pointing directly to the binaries folder, not the whole build directory, so neither location actually contains the .cmake file, only that folders parent.  I'm interested in this specifically because I have both pre-compiled libraries and libraries compiled on my own and I want to know which one I'm using.  Both libraries contain respective OpencvConfig.cmake files.